# Is there a way to check if 2FA code has timed out in ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, two-factor-authentication

When using [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class for login and authentication with 2FA, there's a time limit of a few minutes to enter the 2FA code.

If the user takes too long to enter the code, `GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync()` returns null, like this:

```
var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();

if (user == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Took too long to enter 2FA SMS code");
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way to find out if they took too long. Seems like there would be a more elegant or "official" way to check this (seems likely `GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync` might return null for other reasons. It'd be nice to not tell the user they took too long if they didn't).

Is there a built-in property or something containing the time the 2FA code (e.g.: the number in SMS message) was sent?

Or some other way to check if the 2FA has timed out, other than just checking for null?

Comment: Note that the implementation doesn't necessarily send a code to the user, HOTP and TOTP for example merely check if the entered OTP is currently valid (usually plus or minus a few cycles to account user's inaccurate clock), in such cases checking if the user took too long to copy paste the OTP versus mistyping the code require checking more cycles backward. So any solution would be specific to the implementation.

Comment: The typical 2fa implementation is effectively `Hash(Key + Round(CurrentTime))`. To know if the code is valid, but old, you would need to recreate the history of valid codes and check them all. The point of this design is to reduce storage and cpu load when an attacker tries to brute force a login.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman In my case, don't care if a code is "valid but old". I'm not trying to let them through if expired. All I want to know is, after they enter the 2FA code and submit it, is it now so long since it was sent that the 2FA code has timed out.

Comment: Nothing is stored, deliberately, because you would need to store data for every invalid login attempt. Which would allow an attacker to waste your storage with invalid codes. Hashes are one way functions, and the answers are pigeon holed, so you can't work backwards. Which means you would have to work forwards, by recreating each old 2fa code. That's the only method, and it's a bad idea. Giving any attacker any information about why they were wrong, will allow them to narrow in on the right answer. "That's wrong, but you were close..."